# how do put %span inside rails link_to in haml

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hyperlink, haml, font-awesome, link-to

font awesome inside link_to helper with haml
how should I do?
i have this code

```
.link_header
    {link_to_ledger(current_ledger) span.icon-flag }
```

help please

Comment: How `link_to_ledger` method looks like?

Answer (score 1):

Just pass `span` as block to `link_to` helper method something like following:

`.link_header
   = link_to_ledger(current_ledger) do
     span.icon-flag`

Answer (score 1):

There are two options for link in rails

1. As simple

`= link_to 'my link text', controllers_path`

2. As you want to do

`.link_header
  = link_to_ledger(current_ledger) do
    %span.icon-flag
    -# you can also do what ever you want here even table/images can also be added`